Sticky HTML5 video's z-index is ignored until it finishes
I have a page with a HTML5 video surrounded by dummy content at the top and at the bottom. The goal is to show how the video is looking in the context of a content-rich page.
The video is displayed using a "interscroller effect". This is a common solution in the advertisement industry where the display time of an ad is being maximised. It works by setting position: sticky together with e.g. bottom: 0 on the video element and combining it with a lower z-index than the actual content. That way the video is always at the bottom of the page but hidden behind the content. Then, when scrolling down, at some point the video is revealed by the overlaying text.
This works fine, however when scrolling past the HTML5 video element and going back to the top of the page, it's being displayed on top of the content, although that shouldn't be possible due to the lower z-index. This happens on three major browsers I tested it with (mobile and desktop): Safari, Chrome and Firefox.
It's like after scrolling past the video and revealing it, the z-index of the element is messed up. Now the funny part is, after the video (which is playing in a loop of ~ 10 seconds) finishes, the z-index seems to be reset and the video disappears behind the content again (as it should when you're at the top of the page again after scrolling around).
I tried to create a minimal example of the issue without too much styling and it still occurs, so I assume there's some deeper CSS-Browser-Engine-related issue with the video element combined with position: sticky and the z-index.
A minimal example looks like this: https://codepen.io/xteroz/pen/PoMPNWW
Now, the irony is, when running this in codepen, everything looks as it should. To reproduce the behaviour, take the HTML and the CSS and put it into a single file:
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        *,
        ::before,
        ::after {
            --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
            --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
            --tw-translate-x: 0;
            --tw-translate-y: 0;
            --tw-rotate: 0;
            --tw-skew-x: 0;
            --tw-skew-y: 0;
            --tw-scale-x: 1;
            --tw-scale-y: 1;
            --tw-pan-x: ;
            --tw-pan-y: ;
            --tw-pinch-zoom: ;
            --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
            --tw-gradient-from-position: ;
            --tw-gradient-via-position: ;
            --tw-gradient-to-position: ;
            --tw-ordinal: ;
            --tw-slashed-zero: ;
            --tw-numeric-figure: ;
            --tw-numeric-spacing: ;
            --tw-numeric-fraction: ;
            --tw-ring-inset: ;
            --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
            --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
            --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
            --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
            --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
            --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
            --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
            --tw-blur: ;
            --tw-brightness: ;
            --tw-contrast: ;
            --tw-grayscale: ;
            --tw-hue-rotate: ;
            --tw-invert: ;
            --tw-saturate: ;
            --tw-sepia: ;
            --tw-drop-shadow: ;
            --tw-backdrop-blur: ;
            --tw-backdrop-brightness: ;
            --tw-backdrop-contrast: ;
            --tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;
            --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;
            --tw-backdrop-invert: ;
            --tw-backdrop-opacity: ;
            --tw-backdrop-saturate: ;
            --tw-backdrop-sepia: ;
            --tw-contain-size: ;
            --tw-contain-layout: ;
            --tw-contain-paint: ;
            --tw-contain-style: ;
        }

        ::backdrop {
            --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
            --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
            --tw-translate-x: 0;
            --tw-translate-y: 0;
            --tw-rotate: 0;
            --tw-skew-x: 0;
            --tw-skew-y: 0;
            --tw-scale-x: 1;
            --tw-scale-y: 1;
            --tw-pan-x: ;
            --tw-pan-y: ;
            --tw-pinch-zoom: ;
            --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
            --tw-gradient-from-position: ;
            --tw-gradient-via-position: ;
            --tw-gradient-to-position: ;
            --tw-ordinal: ;
            --tw-slashed-zero: ;
            --tw-numeric-figure: ;
            --tw-numeric-spacing: ;
            --tw-numeric-fraction: ;
            --tw-ring-inset: ;
            --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
            --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
            --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
            --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
            --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
            --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
            --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
            --tw-blur: ;
            --tw-brightness: ;
            --tw-contrast: ;
            --tw-grayscale: ;
            --tw-hue-rotate: ;
            --tw-invert: ;
            --tw-saturate: ;
            --tw-sepia: ;
            --tw-drop-shadow: ;
            --tw-backdrop-blur: ;
            --tw-backdrop-brightness: ;
            --tw-backdrop-contrast: ;
            --tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;
            --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;
            --tw-backdrop-invert: ;
            --tw-backdrop-opacity: ;
            --tw-backdrop-saturate: ;
            --tw-backdrop-sepia: ;
            --tw-contain-size: ;
            --tw-contain-layout: ;
            --tw-contain-paint: ;
            --tw-contain-style: ;
        }

        /*
! tailwindcss v3.4.13 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com
*/
        /*
1. Prevent padding and border from affecting element width. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/4)
2. Allow adding a border to an element by just adding a border-width. (https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/pull/116)
*/
        *,
        ::before,
        ::after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            /* 1 */
            border-width: 0;
            /* 2 */
            border-style: solid;
            /* 2 */
            border-color: #e5e7eb;
            /* 2 */
        }

        ::before,
        ::after {
            --tw-content: '';
        }

        /*
1. Use a consistent sensible line-height in all browsers.
2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
3. Use a more readable tab size.
4. Use the user's configured `sans` font-family by default.
5. Use the user's configured `sans` font-feature-settings by default.
6. Use the user's configured `sans` font-variation-settings by default.
7. Disable tap highlights on iOS
*/
        html,
        :host {
            line-height: 1.5;
            /* 1 */
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            /* 2 */
            -moz-tab-size: 4;
            /* 3 */
            tab-size: 4;
            /* 3 */
            font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
            /* 4 */
            font-feature-settings: normal;
            /* 5 */
            font-variation-settings: normal;
            /* 6 */
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
            /* 7 */
        }

        /*
1. Remove the margin in all browsers.
2. Inherit line-height from `html` so users can set them as a class directly on the `html` element.
*/
        body {
            margin: 0;
            /* 1 */
            line-height: inherit;
            /* 2 */
        }

        /*
1. Add the correct height in Firefox.
2. Correct the inheritance of border color in Firefox. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190655)
3. Ensure horizontal rules are visible by default.
*/
        hr {
            height: 0;
            /* 1 */
            color: inherit;
            /* 2 */
            border-top-width: 1px;
            /* 3 */
        }

        /*
Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
*/
        abbr:where([title]) {
            text-decoration: underline dotted;
        }

        /*
Remove the default font size and weight for headings.
*/
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6 {
            font-size: inherit;
            font-weight: inherit;
        }

        /*
Reset links to optimize for opt-in styling instead of opt-out.
*/
        a {
            color: inherit;
            text-decoration: inherit;
        }

        /*
Add the correct font weight in Edge and Safari.
*/
        b,
        strong {
            font-weight: bolder;
        }

        /*
1. Use the user's configured `mono` font-family by default.
2. Use the user's configured `mono` font-feature-settings by default.
3. Use the user's configured `mono` font-variation-settings by default.
4. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
*/
        code,
        kbd,
        samp,
        pre {
            font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
            /* 1 */
            font-feature-settings: normal;
            /* 2 */
            font-variation-settings: normal;
            /* 3 */
            font-size: 1em;
            /* 4 */
        }

        /*
Add the correct font size in all browsers.
*/
        small {
            font-size: 80%;
        }

        /*
Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in all browsers.
*/
        sub,
        sup {
            font-size: 75%;
            line-height: 0;
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: baseline;
        }

        sub {
            bottom: -0.25em;
        }

        sup {
            top: -0.5em;
        }

        /*
1. Remove text indentation from table contents in Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=999088, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201297)
2. Correct table border color inheritance in all Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=935729, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195016)
3. Remove gaps between table borders by default.
*/
        table {
            text-indent: 0;
            /* 1 */
            border-color: inherit;
            /* 2 */
            border-collapse: collapse;
            /* 3 */
        }

        /*
1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
3. Remove default padding in all browsers.
*/
        button,
        input,
        optgroup,
        select,
        textarea {
            font-family: inherit;
            /* 1 */
            font-feature-settings: inherit;
            /* 1 */
            font-variation-settings: inherit;
            /* 1 */
            font-size: 100%;
            /* 1 */
            font-weight: inherit;
            /* 1 */
            line-height: inherit;
            /* 1 */
            letter-spacing: inherit;
            /* 1 */
            color: inherit;
            /* 1 */
            margin: 0;
            /* 2 */
            padding: 0;
            /* 3 */
        }

        /*
Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge and Firefox.
*/
        button,
        select {
            text-transform: none;
        }

        /*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Remove default button styles.
*/
        button,
        input:where([type='button']),
        input:where([type='reset']),
        input:where([type='submit']) {
            -webkit-appearance: button;
            /* 1 */
            background-color: transparent;
            /* 2 */
            background-image: none;
            /* 2 */
        }

        /*
Use the modern Firefox focus style for all focusable elements.
*/
        :-moz-focusring {
            outline: auto;
        }

        /*
Remove the additional `:invalid` styles in Firefox. (https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/2f9eacd9d3d995c937b4251a5557d95d494c9be1/layout/style/res/forms.css#L728-L737)
*/
        :-moz-ui-invalid {
            box-shadow: none;
        }

        /*
Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome and Firefox.
*/
        progress {
            vertical-align: baseline;
        }

        /*
Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Safari.
*/
        ::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
        ::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
            height: auto;
        }

        /*
1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
*/
        [type='search'] {
            -webkit-appearance: textfield;
            /* 1 */
            outline-offset: -2px;
            /* 2 */
        }

        /*
Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
*/
        ::-webkit-search-decoration {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
        }

        /*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
*/
        ::-webkit-file-upload-button {
            -webkit-appearance: button;
            /* 1 */
            font: inherit;
            /* 2 */
        }

        /*
Add the correct display in Chrome and Safari.
*/
        summary {
            display: list-item;
        }

        /*
Removes the default spacing and border for appropriate elements.
*/
        blockquote,
        dl,
        dd,
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6,
        hr,
        figure,
        p,
        pre {
            margin: 0;
        }

        fieldset {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        legend {
            padding: 0;
        }

        ol,
        ul,
        menu {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        /*
Reset default styling for dialogs.
*/
        dialog {
            padding: 0;
        }

        /*
Prevent resizing textareas horizontally by default.
*/
        textarea {
            resize: vertical;
        }

        /*
1. Reset the default placeholder opacity in Firefox. (https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3300)
2. Set the default placeholder color to the user's configured gray 400 color.
*/
        input::placeholder,
        textarea::placeholder {
            opacity: 1;
            /* 1 */
            color: #9ca3af;
            /* 2 */
        }

        /*
Set the default cursor for buttons.
*/
        button,
        [role="button"] {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /*
Make sure disabled buttons don't get the pointer cursor.
*/
        :disabled {
            cursor: default;
        }

        /*
1. Make replaced elements `display: block` by default. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
2. Add `vertical-align: middle` to align replaced elements more sensibly by default. (https://github.com/jensimmons/cssremedy/issues/14#issuecomment-634934210)
   This can trigger a poorly considered lint error in some tools but is included by design.
*/
        img,
        svg,
        video,
        canvas,
        audio,
        iframe,
        embed,
        object {
            display: block;
            /* 1 */
            vertical-align: middle;
            /* 2 */
        }

        /*
Constrain images and videos to the parent width and preserve their intrinsic aspect ratio. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
*/
        img,
        video {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        /* Make elements with the HTML hidden attribute stay hidden by default */
        [hidden] {
            display: none;
        }

        .relative {
            position: relative;
        }

        .sticky {
            position: sticky;
        }

        .bottom-0 {
            bottom: 0px;
        }

        .z-10 {
            z-index: 10;
        }

        .z-20 {
            z-index: 20;
        }

        .-mx-10 {
            margin-left: -2.5rem;
            margin-right: -2.5rem;
        }

        .mx-auto {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .block {
            display: block;
        }

        .flex {
            display: flex;
        }

        .w-full {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .max-w-4xl {
            max-width: 56rem;
        }

        .justify-center {
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .rounded {
            border-radius: 0.25rem;
        }

        .bg-white {
            --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
            background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-4xl">
        <div class="relative z-20 bg-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
            eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
            justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
            amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
            labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
            rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor
            sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
            gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
            sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
            voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
            takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
            sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
            eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
            tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
            duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
            clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
            sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
            sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
            elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
            vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
            tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
            duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
            clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
            sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
            sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
            elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
            vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
            tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
            duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
            clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
            sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
            sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
            elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
            vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
            tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
            duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
            clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
            sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
            sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
            elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
            vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
            tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
            duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
            clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        <div class="sticky bottom-0 z-10">
            <div class="sticky bottom-0 z-10 flex justify-center">
                <video id="video" ref="video" autoplay preload playsinline muted loop
                    class="relative z-10 block w-full rounded">
                    <source src="https://sample-videos.com/video321/mp4/360/big_buck_bunny_360p_1mb.mp4"
                        type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="relative z-20 bg-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
            eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
            justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
            amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
            labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
            rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor
            sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
            gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
            sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
            voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
            takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
            sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
            eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
            tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
            duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
            clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
            sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
            sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
            elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
            vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
            tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
            duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
            clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
            sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
            sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

Now when opening that file in a browser, scrolling down and up again, the video is stuck at the bottom of the page, no matter where on the page you are scrolling-wise. And in the second the video is over and starts again, everything is back to normal.

Could you put the relevant CSS and HTML actually into your example code within the question so it is easy for us to copy? (and also so it doeant disappear in future when the codepen is deleted so it's a useful question for future readers).

Amended the HTML, I deliberately didn't put it in there initially because you need a lot of lorem ipsum above and below the video to actually trigger the bug. I needed to short it down, so I hope it's still reproducible like this.

Nothing seems to happen in the gap where the video might be. (And you can always use  to create lines, or even a div with 100vh height to create scrolling).
